# Enable cursor keys in python shell over ssh

Tags: python, readline, line-editor, openelec

I run OpenElec on a Pi.
I can ssh to the Pi and open a python shell.

How do I enable the cursor keys to work like `up` getting to last command in the python shell, like it does on my Ubuntu box.

Now the cursor key `up` just shows:
`>>> ^[[A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenElec [compiles Python](https://github.com/OpenELEC/OpenELEC.tv/blob/master/packages/lang/Python/package.mk) with readline support disabled. [Readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) is the line edition library that the interactive Python interpreter uses, so without it, cursor keys won't work.

The readline library is present on the system, so you can compile [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/) (a small wrapper that provides readline command line edition to any command) and run `rlwrap python`. You'll need to [install compilation tools](http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php/Compile_from_source) on our Ubuntu PC, then download the source of rlwrap and compile it. Alternatively there may be a suitable ARM binary of `rlwrap` somwehere.

You can also install [rlwrap](http://packages.ubuntu.com/rlwrap) on your PC and run `rlwrap ssh pi python`.

Comment: Thx. Running `rlwrap ssh pi python` isn't exactly working very well. But I get your drift. I guess Python development is better done in Raspbian on the Pi. And I found some info I was looking for in [Pydocs on the Kodi Wiki](http://kodi.wiki/view/PyDocs)